# Get Password Credentials by WebServiceContext using basic authentication

Tags: java, web-services

I want to know username and password of a HTTP request using basic authentication.

I´m using WebServiceContext.

```
  @Resource
  private WebServiceContext context;
```

I can know the username by using context.getUserPrincipal().toString()

But I still want to know the password.By making debug I am allowed to see my password, which is password.

[image]

How can I retrieve the submitted password accessing only the `WebServiceContext`?

I can see it on debug, can´t I access it directly from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

password is a `char array`, if you use `toString()` you will return the memory address of the array.

instead, use `String.valueOf(passwordAsCharArray);`

Assuming you have the correct getters,

```
String.valueOf(( new ArrayList<PasswordCredential>((((Subject)context.getMessageContex‌​t().get("‌​CLIENT_SUBJECT")).get‌‌​‌​‌​‌​​PrivCredentials‌​())).get(0)).getPassword());
```